# ArbNumerics in julia

Tags: julia

I am not able to work with a high precision using ArbNumerics. I need to have 250 decimal places of precision. The BigFloat package works, but it is slow.

an example, when I do:

```
setprecision(900)
b = ArbFloat("1.0000000000000000000000000000001")
println("b:", b)
```

I get only `b = 1.0`

I tried to change the precision with the setprecision function, but it didn't help at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setprecision` with the type of number you want to use:

```
julia> setprecision(ArbFloat, 750)
750

julia> ArbFloat("1.0000000000000000000000000000001")
1.00000000000000000000000000000009999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999512871382094399127769154594830235079365870142885299440711678888727627293832308245254666478938258516953806897722473139280527115089066911030740714139

julia> setprecision(ArbFloat, 300)
300

julia> ArbFloat("1.0000000000000000000000000000001")
1.00000000000000000000000000000009999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999512871382094
```